# "actual does not contain expected" when using "!contains deep"

Tags: karate

I'm getting some unexpected behavior and a strange error message when trying to check some array contents with `!contains deep` in Karate. I'm trying to verify that my list of people objects contains an object for Alice, but not for Charlie:

```
* def people = [ {"name": "Alice", "phone": 123}, {"name": "Bob", "phone": 456} ]
* def alice = { "name": "Alice" }
* def charlie = { "name": "Charlie" }

# assert Alice is present and Charlie is not

# all of these work
* match people contains deep alice
* match people == '#(^+alice)'
* match people != '#(^+charlie)'
* match each people[*] !contains charlie

# but this doesn't
* match people !contains deep charlie
```

The last check fails:

```
match failed: CONTAINS_DEEP
  $ | actual does not contain expected | actual array does not contain expected item - {"name":"Charlie"} (LIST:MAP)
  [{"name":"Alice","phone":123},{"name":"Bob","phone":456}]
  {"name":"Charlie"}

    $[1] | actual does not contain expected | all key-values did not match, expected has un-matched keys - [name] (MAP:MAP)
    {"name":"Bob","phone":456}
    {"name":"Charlie"}

      $[1].name | not equal (STRING:STRING)
      'Bob'
      'Charlie'

        $[0] | actual does not contain expected | all key-values did not match, expected has un-matched keys - [name] (MAP:MAP)
        {"name":"Alice","phone":123}
        {"name":"Charlie"}

          $[0].name | not equal (STRING:STRING)
          'Alice'
          'Charlie'
```

This looks like what I'd expect for `contains`, so the `!` seems to be ignored here? Is that a bug, or was combining `contains deep` and `!contains` just too optimistic (I have noticed that the documentation mentions them only separately)?

(In the second case, is there a possibility to simply negate an entire `match`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to get you what you want:

```
* match each people !contains charlie
```

So the recommendation is to prefer a `match each` if operating on an array.

Yes, I don't think that `!contains deep` is implemented - and let me just say that you are most welcome to contribute code to fix this or the error message - or documentation to inform users of this limitation.